# Javascript - Prevent Back Button Android From Exit Browser

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, back-button

I have angular single app page application website not cordova, ionic etc., pure javascript and when I enter to the link, I would like to prevent user from press back button. The user will be able to close the browser by pressing home button.

Is it possible in javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(e) {e.preventDefault();})` to disable the back button.